# Java script submit form countdown no reset if refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<button type="submit" class="submitbtn"  id="submit" disabled="disabled" name="submit"  >Submit Form</button>
<p id="timeLeft"> You can send form again after: 86400 seconds </p>
  </div>

  </form>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout (function(){
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = null;
        },86400000);

        var countdownNum = 86400;
        incTimer();

        function incTimer(){
        setTimeout (function(){
            if(countdownNum != 0){
            countdownNum--;
            document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = 'You can send form again after: ' + countdownNum + ' seconds&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '(24hours)';
            incTimer();
            } else {
            document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = 'You can now make a result again!';
            }
        },1000);
        }
    </script>
```

This is my javacode, but if i refersh the page, the countdown also refresh..this submit form disabled and it will submit again after 24hours (86,400 secs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localstorage if you want to save the variable

```
// Put the object into storage when ever you change
localStorage.setItem('countdownNum', countdownNum);

// Retrieve the object from storage when at the starting
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('countdownNum');
if(!retrievedObject){
  retrievedObject= 86400;
}
```

EDIT:
You can change your code to this
https://jsfiddle.net/ammar08429/v0pafq0s/2/

and use setInterval instead of call timeout every second
You can see the example in the above link

Comment: ok thankyou! but , what if i change , i set 3mins, or 1hour? why nothing happens if i change the countdownNum?

Comment: If you want to change the countdoown number
delete the localstorage data and change the number 86400 to whatever you want;

In settimeout you add this
countdownNum*1000
because countdownNum is seconds whereas the number in settimeout is milisecond